# Aspect ratio in Sage and in Google charts

Tags: javascript, charts

I did charts in Sage and there I can choose aspect ratio:

The aspect ratio describes the apparently height/width ratio of a unit square. If you want the vertical units to be as big as the horizontal units, specify an aspect ratio of 1.

```
show(circle((1,1), 1) + plot(x^2, (x,0,5)), aspect_ratio=1)
```

Now I am using google app engine and googles charts. I can't figure out how to set aspect ratio there. For example, shape1 and shape 2  are both [-1;1] X and [-1;1] Y. But on the screen it looks like rectangle because I set "width: 600, height: 400".

```
function drawVisualization() {
// Create and populate the data table.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'X');
data.addColumn('number', 'Shape 1');
data.addColumn('number', 'Shape 2');
for (var i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
  data.addRow([Math.sin(i / 5) * 0.25, Math.cos(i / 25), null])
}
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  data.addRow([Math.sin(i / 25), null, Math.cos(i / 10) * 0.5]);
}

// Create and draw the visualization.
var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(
    document.getElementById('visualization'));
chart.draw(data, {title: 'Cool shapes',
                  width: 600, height: 400,
                  vAxis: {title: "Y", titleTextStyle: {color: "green"}},
                  hAxis: {title: "X", titleTextStyle: {color: "green"}}}
          );
}
```

​

Comment: Is this javascript in the App engine?  You may want to retag your question if that's the case...

Comment: Yes, this is it. I've changed tag.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me is to specify `width` and `height` to be equal and then explicitly specifying the `hAxis.minValue`, `hAxis.maxValue` and `vAxis.minValue`, `vAxis.maxValue`. I compute the xspan and yspan of my data, choose the maximum of the two and them calculate the hAxis and vAxis min/max values accordingly.